# Antlr tokens with multiple assignments

Tags: antlr, token, antlr3

I have a token I want to have 2 assignments be valid and im trying to figure out the best way to do it.

For example I have

```
TOSTRING = 'tostring'
```

But I also want 'toString' to be valid like so:

```
TOSTRING = 'toString'
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:
I want to have it output to the *.token file as

```
TOSTRING=9
'toString'=9
'tostring'=9
```

my code that uses the language uses this structure and putting TOSTRING='tostring' in the token{ } section generates this. Even lexer rules with a single assignment does this. But when I have multiple assignments tokens are not make for 'toString' or 'tostring'

Comment: I missed "my code ... uses this structure" in the question, sorry. If you want to read the .token file in your code, just be aware that ANTLR is only going to create associations in it for token names and token ids. Anything *not* in there after generating the lexer/parser is something ANTLR doesn't care about. What is it that your code does with this file? Could we talk about finding an alternative to reading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, don't use the tokens section as you lose some control of the lexer. Always use real lexer rules. The tokens section just automatically adds lexer rules anyway. There is no difference except you start to run in to the limitations when you want more than just a simple string.

If you want case independence, then see the article here:

[How do I get Case independence?](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1782)

But implement it via the override of LA() (described there) and not the 'A'|'a' methods, which will generate lots of code you don't need. If it is JUST this camel case then:

```
TOSTRING
    : 'to' ('s' | 'S') 'tring'
    ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is to define the lexer rule `TOSTRING` to accept both:

```
TOSTRING
    : 'tostring'   //alternative #1, lower-case 's'
    | 'toString'   //alternative #2, upper-case 'S'
    ;
```

or the equivalent:

```
TOSTRING
    : 'to' ('s' | 'S') 'tring'
    ;
```

Comment: It was already a good answer, but now it's an even better one! ;)

Comment: Is there anything that can be done while keeping the token assignment? 'TOSTRING='

Comment: @merjr I'm not sure what you mean by "keeping the token assignment." Could you update the question with an example of the input you're parsing and the grammar that will parse it? Then I can add a better response to the answer rather than trying to help in comments.

Comment: I'm trying to define it in the tokens{ } section. It is defined currently as TOSTRING='tostring' currently. I want to be able to use tostring and toString in the language. Ill post more info in the question shortly.

Comment: @merjr, no, you can't do that in the `tokens { ... }` block. You'll need actual lexer rules, as tenterhook suggested. No way around it.